# Uploading image using the <img attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to see if it is possible to upload an image from the `<img src="">` to a database, without using the input function

```
<form class="form-horizontal" validate="true" action="upload1.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeForm()"</a>
     <img id="output" src="name.png" data-name="photo" width="100%"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="photo" id="output" value="">
     <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Update Status" class="btn btn-solid">
</form>
```

I just want to know if there's a way it could work

Comment: What is the point to uploading an image that is already on your server?

Comment: I’m trying to upload it to another table on the database

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you do not want to use an input field, since this makes the image upload easier and also provides you a File object which inherits from a Blob and provides you info about the image like filename, lastModified, etc (see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)).

Regardless, yes this is possible in javascript using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). However, you would have to either convert the image to base64 (which I do not recommend because this makes the size about 33% larger), or use a Blob object and upload that (which also involves a hacky workaround using fetch). Here is an example of what you could do.

```
// Convert img to Blob
const img = document.getElementById('output');

fetch(img.src)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
   // Prepare image for upload
   const fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('uploadedImage', blob, 'tmp.png');

   // Upload
   fetch(<image-upload-endpoint>, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: fd     
   })
   .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
         // Upload was successful
      } else {
         // Upload failed
      }
   });
});
```

Then you would be able to retrieve the file in PHP with $_FILES['uploadedImage']